# Django Multi Table/Database queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two Model

```
class User(models.Model)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

class Blog(models.Model)
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Because User in db User, and Blog in db Blog_1, Blog_2...Blog8, so without ForeignKey

In bloglist views, I want to show blogs with username. 
How do it with one query? or must have multi queryset?
`Blog.objects.all()` get the user_id, and query every username by user_id ?

And bloglist views show the blogs from the user following, I have a blogid list, but blogs from multi db, so:

```
for id in blogid_list
    Blog.objects.get(pk=id).using('Blog_%d' % (id % 8))
```

How combine in one list?
I think the code is inefficient, any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the user_id as an integer and then query your blog-database in a second step.

Django does not support cross-database relationships. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations)